# Troubleshooting Azure AKS Autoscale

Tags: azure, azure-aks

We are working with the preview feature for AKS Cluster Autoscale. We have it all setup with the VMSS support. However in our tests it does not scale/add nodes. We get errors that 0/2 nodes are available and no more replicas can be added. A while later i did see it add one node but a lot of replicas are still red/failed. What is the best way to go about troubleshooting this. I looked at the autoscale status. but it did not show any errors. I recall doing something similar with the Regular Kubernetes autoscale and was able to pour through some logs to find the issues. But i cant find anything in the logs about this? What logs to look at? and if you are feeling generous. What are you seeing for amount of time the cluster takes to add a node and those pod add failures to go away?

Searching logs. add replicas slower

Comment: raise an issue on AKS github

Comment: Do you have a vm cpu limit on your subscription?